# Gstreamer on Mac Plugins not working

Tags: macos, gstreamer

I have some serious issues with GStreamer on my Mac OS X 10.10.3 System.
I installed gstreamer, gst-libav, -python, -validate, gst-plugins-base, -good, -bad, -ugly via Homebrew

but the only working example for me right now is:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink`

If I try something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5200
```

I get an error: no element >>jpegenc<<

Does anyone have a clue how I get this to work?

THX
snuef

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem as well. Here is the solution:

```
brew install gst-plugins-good  --with-jpeg
```

Turns out that while `jpegenc` is included in the 'good' plugins, it is not installed by default by homebrew. You have to specify `--with-jpeg`

This is the output of `brew info`. As you can see, jpeg support is not the only thing that is not installed by default with homebrew.

```
$ brew info gst-plugins-good
gst-plugins-good: stable 1.6.1 (bottled), HEAD
GStreamer plugins (well-supported, under the LGPL)
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-good/1.6.0 (363 files, 13M)
  Poured from bottle
/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-good/1.6.1 (365 files, 13M) *
  Built from source with: --with-jpeg
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/gst-plugins-good.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: xz ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: gettext ✔, gst-plugins-base ✔, libsoup ✔
Optional: check ✘, orc ✘, gtk+ ✔, aalib ✘, libcdio ✘, esound ✘, flac ✘, jpeg ✔, libcaca ✘, libdv ✘, libshout ✘, speex ✘, taglib ✘, libpng ✔, libvpx ✘
==> Options
--with-aalib
    Build with aalib support
--with-check
    Build with check support
--with-esound
    Build with esound support
--with-flac
    Build with flac support
--with-gtk+
    Build with gtk+ support
--with-jpeg
    Build with jpeg support
--with-libcaca
    Build with libcaca support
--with-libcdio
    Build with libcdio support
--with-libdv
    Build with libdv support
--with-libpng
    Build with libpng support
--with-libshout
    Build with libshout support
--with-libvpx
    Build with libvpx support
--with-orc
    Build with orc support
--with-speex
    Build with speex support
--with-taglib
    Build with taglib support
--with-x11
    Build with x11 support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Comment: This saved me when running into the no motioncells plugin found. I did `brew info gat-plugins-bad` and found the proper `--with-opencv@2` and reinstalled. Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing any of the --with options, only --HEAD. Could this have something to do with the recent update to brew 2.0.0?